# Standardising pydantic models for similar APIs

Tags: python, pydantic

I'm consuming a set of similar APIs, that all return a broadly standard structures.

The code below sets up the pydantic model for `Api1`

I now need to do the model for `Api2`. The structure is the same but only the field names are different. Is it possible to create reusable code so that I can keep the standard model, and only create classes for each of the different API calls?

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

api1 = {
    'status': True,
    'message': 'Successful',
    'data': {
        'records': [{
            'api1field1': 'api1value1',
            'api1field2': 'api1value2',
            'api1field3': 'api1value3'
        }],
        'count': 1
    },
    'code': 200
}

class Api1(BaseModel):
    api1field1: str
    api1field2: str
    api1field3: str


class StandardData(BaseModel):
    records: List[Api1]
    count: int


class CommonModel(BaseModel):
    status: bool
    message: str
    data: StandardData
    code: int


model = CommonModel(**api1)

# Happy so far. But now on to Api2

api2 = {
    'status': True,
    'message': 'Successful',
    'data': {
        'records': [
            {
                'api2field1': 'api2value1',
                'api2field2': 'api2value2',
                'api2field3': 'api2value3'
            },
            {
                'api2field1': 'api2value4',
                'api2field2': 'api2value5',
                'api2field3': 'api2value6'
            }
        ],
        'count': 2
    },
    'code': 200
}
```

How do I set this up to reuse the standard models used for Api1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a [generic model](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#generic-models). If you want to be extra specific, you can constrain the type variable to your specific "record" models.

#### Code

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel


class Foo(BaseModel):
    x: str
    y: int


class Bar(BaseModel):
    a: float
    b: bool


RecordT = TypeVar("RecordT", Foo, Bar)


class StandardData(GenericModel, Generic[RecordT]):
    records: list[RecordT]
    count: int


class CommonModel(GenericModel, Generic[RecordT]):
    status: bool
    data: StandardData[RecordT]
```

#### Demo

```py
test_data_foo = {
    "status": True,
    "data": {
        "records": [
            {
                "x": "spam",
                "y": -1,
            }
        ],
        "count": 1,
    },
}
test_data_bar = {
    "status": True,
    "data": {
        "records": [
            {
                "a": 3.14,
                "b": False,
            },
            {
                "a": 0.0,
                "b": True,
            },
        ],
        "count": 2,
    },
}

obj_foo = CommonModel[Foo].parse_obj(test_data_foo)
obj_bar = CommonModel[Bar].parse_obj(test_data_bar)
print(obj_foo.json(indent=4))
print(obj_bar.json(indent=4))
```

#### Output

```json
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "records": [
            {
                "x": "spam",
                "y": -1
            }
        ],
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "records": [
            {
                "a": 3.14,
                "b": false
            },
            {
                "a": 0.0,
                "b": true
            }
        ],
        "count": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect - thanks. I think even if I found the documentation I would have struggled with the double nesting example.